# why can't i str_replace?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, preg-match, str-replace

I'm trying to grab only duration of a video file.

I'm going to use ffmpeg to grab exact 10 thumbnail of any length of video file.
For this i need to find out fist the duration and then divide by 10. to do ffmpeg.

The results are same. The str_replace is not working.
Result:

```
b: [FORMAT] duration=6.048000 [/FORMAT] 
bb: [FORMAT] duration=6.048000 [/FORMAT] 
bbbb: [FORMAT] duration=6.048000 [/FORMAT] 



$_b = array(shell_exec("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffprobe -v quiet -v fatal  -show_format_entry duration  $videoFile"));

$b  = $_b[0];
echo "b: " .$b . "<br/>";
$bb = str_replace("[FORMAT] duration=","",$b);
echo "bb: " .$bb . "<br/>";
$bbbb = str_replace(" [/FORMAT]", "", $bb);
echo "bbbb: " .$bbbb . "<br/>";

//var partsArray = coolVar.split('-');



    for($num=1; $num<=3; $num++)
    {
        $interval=$num*3;
        shell_exec("$ffmpeg -i $videoFile -an -ss $interval -s $size $num.jpg");
        echo "Thumbnail Created........! - $num.jpg <br />";

    }
    echo "<br / >$num thumbnails Created!";
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `preg_match_all()` instead:

```
preg_match_all('~(\w+):.*?duration=([\d.]+).*~', $data, $matches);
```

And to display it, you can use a loop:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($matches); $i++) { 
  echo $matches[1][$i]. ' : ' . $matches[2][$i] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
b : 6.048000
bb : 6.048000
bbbb : 6.048000
```

Comment: I think this is the best way.  I think the str_replace isn't working because it's not an actual space that is between the [FORMAT] tags, but rather a character code or other value.